# Reactjs popup component can we make a refs in button is it possible?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a refs inside the button in react popup component . What i am trying to achieve is when the popup comes in screen i need to make any one of the button focus then user doesn't want to touch the screen he wants to press enter key then the focused button will trigger .
I have tried and that doesnt work me . I am not sure what i am missing also i m new bee for reactjs . Can any one help me is it possible or not in react-popup component .

I have made react popup as reusable function the below code

```
export const createPopup = (msg, type, title, swapColor) => {

  msg = msg === undefined || msg === null ? '' : msg
  title = title === undefined || title === null ? '' : title
  type = type === undefined || type === null ? '' : type
  swapColor = swapColor === undefined || swapColor === null ? false : swapColor


  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    Popup.close();
    Popup.create({
      title: type,
      content: msg,
      className: type,
      closeOnOutsideClick: false,
      buttons: {
        left: [{
          text: type === popupType.CONFIRM ? 'YES' : 'OK',
          className: swapColor === true ? 'cancel' : 'ok',
          key: swapColor === true ? '' : 'enter',
            // is it possible or not if yes please tell how to access 
         ** ref : 'leftRef' **,
          action: function () {
            Popup.close();
            resolve(true);
          }
        }],
        right: [type === popupType.CONFIRM ? {
          text: 'NO',
          key: swapColor === true ? 'enter' : '',
          className: swapColor === true ? 'ok' : 'cancel',
         **ref : 'rightRef'**,
          action: function () {
            Popup.close();
            reject(false);
          }
        } : '']
      }
    })

  })
```

In my component below the way i am accessing ,

```
 this.leftRef.focus(); or  this.rightRef.focus();
```

As mentioned above code ref ='leftRef' is possible or not i dont know if yes how do i make a call that **ref** in another **imported component** . Or is there any better work around please let me know . Thanks in advance !!.

Comment: Is the PopUp, child component of the imported component?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-popup` which I assume from the api your code uses **it is not possible**. [This is how `react-popup` renders these buttons](https://github.com/minutemailer/react-popup/blob/master/src/ButtonsSpace.react.js#L59):

```js
const btnComponent = (
    <ActionButton
        className={className}
        key={key}
        url={url}
        onClick={() => this.buttonClick(btn.action)}
    >
        {btn.text}
    </ActionButton>
);
```

As you can see no ref callback is passed to it.

This library is only suitable if you do not need to modify the appearance or behavior of the popup. It has only a few props to modify it and doesn't provide ways to override anything. This is why I do not like the design of that library because it is somehow against the principle of react to build easily composable components.

**EDIT**:

A way to still make it work is to give the button you would like to focus a unique class name:

```js
Popup.create({
    // ...
    buttons: {
        left: ['NO'],
        right: [{
            text: 'YES',
            className: 'btn-yes', // your unique class name here
            // ...
        }]
    }
});
```

Then you can get the DOM element and focus it like this:

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-yes')[0];
btn.focus();
```

Comment: ,Thank you , is there any way to auto focus on any one button possible ?

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand You could give the button a unique class name and select that DOM node by it's class name with `document.getElementsByClassName()` and manually focus it. It's not the react way but it should work.

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand see my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Sorry for late reply . I tried various way to call the focus as you mentioned but I couldnt get the focus . Can I add the above two line inside my export function or do i call it separate because If I access createpop method from my component i do like this `createpopup(popupmessage, popType , title , color).then(function(ifYespressaction){},fuc(ifNo){})` . I dont know where to add those line . I tried many ways where ever i add it doesnt reflect . Still my cursor in different place . I tried blur then focus but no luck . Could you please guide me where do i those line ., @trixn .